# How can I insert a string into another string?

Tags: php, youtube, embed

I want to insert a string into another string.

I have youtube links:
http://www.youtube.com/9bZkp7q19f0

and I want to add /embed after the .com so that I can embed them on the fly.

How can I make them look like this?:
http://www.youtube.com/embed/9bZkp7q19f0

Answer (score 6):

```
$url = str_replace("youtube.com/", "youtube.com/embed/", $url);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use "substr_replace" which means you are replacing text within a portion of a string.

Have a look to this, can get to know more about substr_replace,
http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php

Answer (score 1):

```
$link = "http://www.youtube.com/9bZkp7q19f0"; 
$link = str_replace("youtube.com/", "youtube.com/embed/", $link);
```

now

```
$link = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/9bZkp7q19f0";
```